# left arrow, left-pointing arrow, or leftwards arrow?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, academia

In the context of a figure caption referencing a left-pointing arrow in the figure in the following parenthetical way:

> Fig. 1 | ... Here I describe some process (left arrow). ...

A colleague suggested "left arrow" should be replaced with "left-pointing arrow?"

After a bit of research online, I seem to see all three versions in use, with "left arrow" being most popular, though in the Chicago Manual of Style, I see the use of "left-pointing arrow" in a different context.

While "left-pointing arrow" is certainly not wrong, is it just as correct and accepted use to say "left arrow"? Or would this be considered more colloquial?  (There is also the option of "leftwards arrow").

Comment: "left-pointing arrow" is probably the least ambiguous.  The others could be interpreted as meaning the arrow on the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Left arrow' could be ambiguous. See the diagram below. Which is the left arrow? A or B?

[image]

To completely avoid ambiguity, you can describe Arrow A as "a right-pointing arrow on the left side of the diagram", and Arrow B is "a left-pointing arrow on the right side of the diagram". If that seems a little too long, "left-pointing arrow" is also perfectly acceptable for Arrow B (and vice versa).

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Curious, what if there is only one arrow in the figure?

Comment: If there is only one arrow, there is no need to add clarifications like “left-pointing”. You can just say “the arrow”. For example, “In Figure 1, the arrow shows the area of greatest population density”.

Comment: @kandyman If you were verbally describing a document, or more likely, a computer screen or web page which had only one arrow on it it might still be useful to say "There is a right-pointing arrow on the left side of your screen, click on it". This would be even more useful if you were talking about a screen where the arrow always appeared in the same place but sometimes it was not visible and sometimes its direction changed in response to circumstances. In that case you might say "If there is a right pointing arrow on the left side of your screen click on it now."

Comment: @BoldBen True, but the question did specify a figure. And I still think that in most cases directional clarifications are redundant if there is only one arrow.

Comment: @kandyman Yes, I think that describing the exact state of a single context-sensitive arrow is probably the _only_  case where you would need to specify it (unless the person you were describing it to was an average IT user, of course)

Answer (score 3):

For what it’s worth (not very much, I imagine) the [Unicode description](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2190/index.htm) is:

> Leftwards Arrow

In that entry you will find “left arrow” as the “old name”, so perhaps they have addressed the problem and their description is actually worth considering.

Comment: I think you're right. See my comment directed at kandyman above. However the code to implement the context-sensitive arrow I was talking about could get away with the old name as it would be revealing and suppressing a 'left arrow' a 'right arrow' and possibly even an 'up arrow' and a 'down arrow' in the same position depending on the state of the data.